# In swift this line _stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(view) always gives same value

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, nsview

I have problem in this line **_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(view)**

I am trying print this **_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(view)** in Xcode debug and getting same value NSView only.

Here is the code I am using

```
if(_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(view) == "NSTextField")
```